# how to show graphically workflow of each items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, tasks, workflow-activity

I designed 4 forms library in infopath2013 which  have dependency to each other (I mean for example when form 1 filled and approved then form 2 must be automatically created via workflow based on its title and then filled by user)I want to show graphically  this progress to user to show to him which level is or which form now must be filled  (for example the page that user first create an item and when it created item for each item he direct  to another page which shows the levels and the user must click on the button to create each form ).

is there a way to do this in sharepoint2013?

Comment: Bro, Do you need to show your workflow graphically or you need to show the current step graphically?

Comment: current step , to show user which forms must  fill and which level is now (to don't be confusing),Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to use tasklist and show them in timeline which not depend on time??